# Writing UTF-8 to a file and downloading it with FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8

I've been working on making a Distributed File System and have come to a halt today with trying to write the contents of a returned file for the browser to download.

My system sends a request for a file's data and gets a string of the entire UTF-8 encoded binary contents as a response. I'm then trying to use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to write and download this content.

It only works for .txt files at the moment. I suspect it's something to do with the encoding and how the Blob object is made, I think it's simply writing the UTF-8 as text to each file which is why it works for .txt and nothing else. I've tried converting the response to byteArrays or using a File object instead but nothing works.

Here's the code doing the request and handling the response:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:3040/read",
  data: {
    data: data
  },
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  success: function(response) {
    var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
    var blob = new Blob([response], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, filename);
  }
});
```

An small snippet of the response output (in this case for a png image):

```
PNG
\u1a
\u0\u0\u1a
IHDR\u0\u0\u2î\u0\u0\u56Eµ¤Q\u0\u0\u0\u1sRGB\u0®Î\u1cé...
```

Comment: Did you tried to set your responseType to arraybuffer?

Comment: @WendelNascimento Not yet. I just tried it using a simple an XMLHttpRequest and setting the responseType to 'blob' (Since AJAX doesn't seem to support it yet) and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!